# How to generate migration with uuid primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uuid

How can a model be generated from the `rails generate` command, specifying `uuid` as the column type for the primary key?

My goal is to issue some command like the following:

```
rails g model widget id{uuid}
```

To generate a migration like

```
create_table :widgets, id: :uuid do |t|
  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

I realize I can add `id: :uuid` after the migration is generated, but I feel like there must be some lazy way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an old post but I wanted to do the same.

**First** - enable uuid : create a new migration file `rails g migration enable_uuid_extension` and edit this file as follow :

```
class EnableUuidExtension < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    enable_extension 'uuid-ossp'
  end
end
```

**Second** - In /config/application.rb, add those 3 lines :

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.orm :active_record, primary_key_type: :uuid
end
```

**Then** ... That's it ! As you wanted `rails g model widget` will generate :

```
create_table :widgets, id: :uuid do |t|
  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

And will do the same for all your next migrations.

[Source](http://www.mccartie.com/2015/10/20/default-uuid's-in-rails.html)

Answer (score 2):

[As of Rails 5.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ff044c3c3a0a85d26d7c000abeeed835a3bee0bf), you can now use the following syntax to opt in for a single migration:

```
rails generate migration CreateWidget widget --primary-key-type=uuid
```

This results in the following migration (generated with Rails 6.0, but the feature remains the same):

```
class CreateWidget < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :widgets, id: :uuid do |t|
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First run it

```
rails g migration CreateWidget uuid:primary_key
```

Then go to the migration file and add `primary_key: "uuid", force: true`

eg

```
class CreateWidget < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :widgets, id: false, force: true do |t|
      t.primary_key :uuid
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, well I was looking for a way to do it from the generator command without editing the migration file. Lazy, I know.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
rails g model widget uuid:primary_key
```

I save this [link](http://railsguides.net/advanced-rails-model-generators/) on Pocket, very useful.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, as it tries to create a new primary key column named "uuid": `CREATE TABLE "widgets" ("id" serial primary key, "uuid" serial primary key...`

Comment: @mysmallidea, sorry. @arv remembered well that you must edit the migration's file to override index and put force params on `create_table`. I forgot this... My bad.